# XPS convert PDF with Ghostscript

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, xps

I need to convert XPS to PDF. The conversion needs to be executed within a .NET 6.0 (C#) application code. I've tried various methods and currently settled on using Ghostscript. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
var ghostscriptPath = "/usr/bin/gs";
using (var process = new Process())
{
    var xpsFilePath = "/mnt/d/Users/Lev/adcm/18/ADCM_Connect/PilotWebApplication/Microsoft+Word+-+ВОР+АД+изм.1 (2).xps"; // Specify the path to your XPS file
    var outputPdfPath = "/mnt/d/Users/Lev/adcm/18/ADCM_Connect/PilotWebApplication/output.pdf"; // Specify the path to save the PDF file

    // Set command line parameters for Ghostscript
    process.StartInfo.FileName = ghostscriptPath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=\"{outputPdfPath}\" \"{xpsFilePath}\"";
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // Start the process
    process.Start();

    // Wait for the process to exit
    process.WaitForExit();
}

pdfStream.Position = 0;
var encodedFileName = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileData.name);
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(encodedFileName, ".pdf")}\"");
```

I'm encountering an error "GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1". Is it possible to solve this task using Ghostscript, and what are the methods to convert XPS to PDF using .NET 6.0?

Comment: You can't be using Ghostscript (because that doesn't handle XPS), you must be using GhostXPS. You should be using a more up to date version, 9.55 is 2 years old and has known vulnerabilities. You haven't provided an example file which would help, nor have you given the back channel transcript (stdout/stderr) which might have more information. In the absence off all that all I can tell you is that GhostXPS found some problem, but you already know that.

Comment: Actually, I see from the code you **are** using Ghostscript, and that's the source of your problem. Ghostscript only handles PostScript and PDF input, not XPS. If you want to deal with XPS you'll either need to use GhostXPS or GhostPDL (which bundles all the family up in one application). You should also check the license to be sure your intended use is AGPL 3 compatible.